# Programmatically set lock on sleep in MacOS Catalina/Big Sur

Tags: bash, macos, settings, macos-catalina, macos-big-sur

I am looking for a way to audit and/or set the screen to lock on sleep on MacOS Catalina and Big Sur. Ideally this would be a setting that could be changed in a shell script or via the command line, as I have over a dozen machines to manage.

Things I have tried:

Using `defaults` to set `com.apple.screensaver askForPassword` and `askForPasswordDelay` to true and 5 seconds respectively. From what I've found, this no longer works as of MacOS 10.13. The only setting I find under that particular key is `tokenRemovalAction`.

Using `system_profiler` to check if this setting is listed under several data types. Among others, I checked `SPSoftwareDataType` and `SPDisplaysDataType`, neither of which gave me the data I need.

Is there something I'm missing? Is it even possible to check or edit this setting outside of MDM?